# Как посимвольно считать буквы из файла?

Tags: c++, файлы

Имеется файл с форматом txt. Нужно с этого файла посимвольно считать буквы. Т.е. из потока берется самая первая буква, шифруется и сразу же записывается в выходной файл уже зашифрованная. С потоком я работать умею, а вот как посимвольно считать?

Answer (score 2):

Один из самых простых способов такой:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream f("file.txt");
    char c;
    while(f.get(c)) {
        // обрабатываете символ с
    } 
}
```

метод [get](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) берет ссылку на char и записывает туда новый символ из потока.